# Why don't high-level parties get scry/teleport ambushed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

In [How opponents buffing affects encounter difficulty](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98778/how-opponents-buffing-affects-encounter-difficulty), a commenter said:

> a teleportation ambush should not happen to a party of level 17 adventurers because either they'll be prepared for that eventuality hence not an ambush or they'll stop it before it starts.

What assumptions are behind this?  Is this assuming that every high-level party will have a spell slot dedicated to *anticipate teleportation* at all times?

Comment: Speaking as someone currently playing in a 3.5 party of comparable level: Neither of those conditions holds true for us. Therefore it is not a universally applicable rule.

Comment: Yeah, I have to say I'm ambivalent about a question that basically just asks "hey what did that dude mean in his comment".  I would suggest retooling this to be more neutral about routine scry-TP defenses; it seems subjective and opinion-based as @WeckarE. points out to say that any of this is universally applicable (as it's trivially obvious that it's not in many campaigns).

Comment: Hm, I think you're right.  I've voted to close this question; feel free to do the same.

Answer (score 6):

*In the answer below I use the phrase* teleportation ambush *to refer to the following tactic: Group A uses a scrying effect to determine Group B's status and location. Then, if Group B is vulnerable and accessible, Group A prepares for battle and uses a teleportation effect to mount a surprise attack against Group B. Also known as scry-and-die, this tactic can devastate PCs, NPCs, the DM, the players, and the campaign. I've yet to meet anyone who* likes *staging or experiencing teleportation ambushes, but the tactic is* so *easy—and the means, like Hawthorne's [birthmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth-Mark), so deeply rooted in the game's foundation—that banning it outright* as a tactic *usually isn't an option.*

## My campaigns' assumptions…

In my campaigns, high-level PCs typically are *not* victims of teleportation ambushes because they learned much earlier in their careers—perhaps before the campaign even began—*both* that teleportation ambushes can occur *and* that they should acquire the means to deal with them.

> #### Examples
>
> If mentors *don't* explain to their apprentices before the campaign begins that teleportation ambushes *are* a thing, when apprentices become adventurers they may learn that teleportation ambushes are a thing alarmingly early on.
>
> - A level 7 wizard (or cleric with the domains Knowledge and Travel)—a difficult challenge for a party of level 3 PCs—can launch a *deeply* ersatz teleportation ambush from over 1/10 of a mile away using the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*clairaudience/clairvoyance*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#clairaudience/clairvoyance) [div] (*PH* 209-10) and the 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*dimension door*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#dimension-door) [conj] (*PH* 221).
> - A level 10 wizard (or cleric with the domain Travel)—a difficult challenge for a party of level 6 PCs—can launch a for-reals teleportation ambush from *a thousand miles away* using the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*scrying*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#scrying) [div] (*PH* 274-5) followed by the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*teleport*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#teleport) [conj] (*PH* 292-3).
>
> Encounter difficulty is as per the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, which also says that as many as 15% of PCs' encounters may be difficult (49). Note, also, that these casters can do this *once per day*.

When I design a campaign, I assume casters *did* do this once a day until folks figured out how to thwart them. Afterward, teleportation ambushes still happen, but they happen rarely and only in unusual circumstances. That doesn't mean, however, that folks get *complacent* about the possibility, but it does mean safeguards have been put in place to prevent the casual murder of civilized folk *via* teleportation ambushes. I mean, if there *aren't* safeguards against teleportation ambushes *already* in place when the campaign begins, I, personally, don't know how to maintain the campaign's verisimilitude. In short, I make sure my campaigns thwart teleportation ambushes (and the shadowpocalypse!) *first* and *then* I figure out the rest.

I address how to deal with scrying effects in another [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/80918/8610) and how to counter teleportation effects in another [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/35857/8610), so I'm not going to rehash those answers at length here except to say that I think, in a typical campaign, the DM should prepare the players for the possibility that their PCs will be, at some point, the victims of a teleport ambush *early* in their careers so the players can be told by the DM how the campaign prevents teleportation ambushes or so the PCs can determine in the campaign how to deal with the tactic.

My point is that I—and *just* me, you totally might not, and that's okay—see the *sudden* introduction *at high levels* of teleportation ambushes as unfair. Since teleportation ambushes could've been a thing as early as level 3, I would feel I'd done the players a disservice by *refraining* from using teleportation ambushes when the tactic became available but *then* springing teleportation ambushes on them after the PCs assumed teleportation ambushes *don't* happen. That is, by introducing the players to teleportation ambushes earlier—when the game isn't quite the rocket-tag it is at high-levels—I give the players the opportunity to figure out how to deal with them. And they do.

See, in my campaigns, I make it clear *from the outset* that *many* walls incorporate thin sheets of lead, some places have permanent [*Mordenkainen's private sanctum*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#mages-private-sanctum) effects, *many* places have [*hallow*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#hallow) effects tied to [*dimensional anchor*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#dimensional-anchor) effects (which allows teleportation effects to be used to *enter* the warded area but not to *exit* the area), a few places even have password-protected [*forbiddance*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#forbiddance) effects (*far* stronger and pricier than the previous combination!), and ["[a]reas of strong physical or magical energy"](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#teleport) litter the landscape… all so important folks, the rabble, *and* adventurers can live (relatively speaking, anyway) safely and fearlessly. And, as older protections fall into disuse or disrepair, important folks enlist those who can to make *more* defenses. Otherwise I imagine their fragile civilization collapsing.

So, yes, I encourage my players to have the party early on acquire a means to detect scrying sensors; to employ the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell *anticipate teleportation* [abjur] (*Spell Compendium* 13) *et al.*, whether by spell, wand, *eternal wand*, minor schema, or whatever; and to overnight at places with lead-lined walls or possessing "strong physical and magical energy." In my campaigns, *Can I hinder or prevent a teleportation ambush?* is just one more thing an adventurer worries about, like *Can I hit an incorporeal creature?* or *What do I do if I contract [mummy rot](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#mummy-rot) in the middle of nowhere?*

Accuse me of lacking imagination all you want, but I just can't imagine a campaign world using the typical *D&D 3.5e* rules existing any other way.

### …But *your* campaign may vary (and, honestly, so do mine!)

In a current campaign I've made a house rule that says that bodies of water sufficient to appear on the campaign map prevent teleportation beyond them, forcing folks to cross rivers and oceans conventionally, and in a previous campaign spooky mists prevented teleportation beyond the valley that was at the center of the campaign. In both cases, the goal was to limit (*not* eradicate) the utility of teleportation and to mitigate (*not* dispense with entirely) the possibility of teleportation ambushes.

So I *really*, *really* don't want to make it sound in that overlong section up above like I'm somehow *mandating* that *my way* is the One True Way to play or anything. It's not. Seriously, I really *can't* know how *your* campaign handles teleportation ambushes—by strict reading, house rules, a gentlemen's agreement among players, a gentlemen's agreement among *wizards*, or whatever!—, but I *do* recommend that *sooner rather than later* that *every* campaign somehow addresses teleportation ambushes.

---

***Note:** I made the Comment mentioned in the [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99105/8610).*

Answer (score 2):

I interpreted it to mean that the party would either be able to foil the scrying part via a spell like *nondetection* or be able to foil the teleportation part through *anticipate teleportation* as you suggested. Alternatively, they could use something like *contingency* that doesn't directly prevent a scry/teleport ambush but does reduce the effectiveness of one.

Personally, I wouldn't say that *every* high-level party is like this. Some reasons I can think of why it might not be the case:

- The players haven't encountered enemies that use abilities like scrying very often, so they aren't prepared for them, or at least don't go so far as to ensure that they have 24/7 protection against it.
- The party has mostly spontaneous casters like sorcerors who might not be willing to dedicate one of their precious known spell slots to something like *nondetection*.

That said, I don't have a great deal of experience in high-level play, so maybe it's more common than I think.

Comment: In a party without dedicated casters at all, I think it is a faulty assumption to begin with.